# How to set the foreground property of a TextBlock in C# for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, textblock, foreground

For some reason I am having a problem setting the foreground of a TextBlock.

I've tried:

- new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color); but there is no Color.White or any colors for that matter.
- I can't find a Brushes.Color class

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be the Colors class (but not Color). Example:

```
var textblocks = new TextBlock() { Height = box_height, Width = box_width, Text = "Hello", FontSize = 30, Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) };
```

Comment: I'm getting a message: 'The name Colors does not exist in the current context'.  It seems strange to me that I don't have the appropriate references for this in a standard page.

Comment: Add at the beginning of the page directive: using Windows.UI;
It should work.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.